# if else time in a specific range

Tags: vba, date, if-statement, time

here the issue; when my code runs it does not recognise that 7:00:00 pm is smaller than 24:00.
I´m writing in cell D2 =TIME(23,59,59)+TIME(0,0,1)

and the code that is a simple comparison, evaluate true when 7:00:00 > 24:00:00

How can I say with UDF that in cell D2 there is midnight for the proper comparison that I need?

here the code and a screenshot:

```
Public Function GetTime1(TIn As Date, TOut As Date, TCheckIn As Date, TCheckOut As Date) As Double

    Dim Hours As Integer

        If Hour(TOut) < Hour(TCheckIn) Then
        Hours = DateDiff("h", TCheckIn, TOut)
        GetTime1 = TimeSerial(Hours, 0, 0)

        ElseIf Hour(TIn) > Hour(TCheckOut) Then
        Hours = DateDiff("h", TIn, TCheckOut)
        GetTime1 = TimeSerial(Hours, 0, 0)

        End If

        End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have only the time in these cells, or only the time is displayed by formatting? Don't you have the date, too? Otherwise, the midnight will be zero time and it is lower then anything else...

Comment: That´s the issue, working with time, no dates.

Comment: Then, you must consider 23:59:59 (11:59:59 PM) like the maximum daily time... What do you want to accomplish, in fact? If checkout took place next day, how do yo intend to deal with such a situation?

Comment: good question, this is just the beginning of what I need to do.
the code needs to recognise if a person is filling the value 12:00:00 am in his shift.... then 23,59,59 can be a problem for giving me the right result

Comment: I am splitting the cell, like form 10:00:00 p.m. to 12:00:00 a.m. and then another cell with 6:00:00 a.m. even if the time range to check is from  10:00:00 p.m to 6:00:00 a.m.

Comment: I am trying to figure out, but I want to do step by step... this is the first issue that I am having, then I´ll be back with the second one... :)

Comment: I would dare to suggest that for the case of 12:00:00 AM to use and `If` and transform it in  11:59:59 PM. An error of a second should not count to much, I would dare to believe...

Comment: What application does fill the cells in discussion? Isn't it possible to adapt it to deal with time including date? It will be much better to use DateDiff...

Comment: I understand what you are saying, but these are many people filling the cells in excel and they are using times, then the functions should work for this thing to recognize the hour and time as per timeshift

Comment: Since it is true that the max time is 23:59:59 (@FaneDuru), you are stuck with working with strings instead of times: `ampm = mid$(stime, 10, 2)` . . `hhmmss = mid$(stime, 1, 8)`. Tough input validation.

Comment: rough, can you help me with some more code? :)

Comment: I have just fixed the issue working with double.... Than a lot of water will pass under the bridge... but so far the code is like this:

Public Function GetTime1(TIn As Date, TOut As Date, TCheckIn As Date, TCheckOut As Date) As Double

Dim Hours As Integer

    If TOut < TCheckOut Then
    Hours = DateDiff("h", TCheckIn, TOut)
    GetTime1 = 0
    
    ElseIf TIn > TCheckOut Then
    Hours = DateDiff("h", TIn, TCheckOut)
    GetTime1 = TimeSerial(Hours, 0, 0)

    End If
    
    End Function

Comment: in this way it compare midnight as it is 1.... ;)